# PostgreSQL FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[ipv6]", user "[user]", database "postgres", no encryption

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-14

Unable to connect to a postgreSQL database on a LAN. (No problems connecting to the db on the server locally)

Error shown in pgAdmin.app:

```
Unable to connect to server: connection to server at "xxx.local" ([ipv6]), port 5432 failed: could not imitiate GSSAPI security context: Miscellaneous failure (see text): Matching credential (krbtgt/LOCAL@LKDC:SHA1.[long hex number] not found (negative cache) connection to server at "[server name]" ([ipv6]), port 5432 failed:
```

Error shown in log: /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@14.log

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[ipv6]", user "[user]", database "postgres", no encryption
```

So the pg server sees the attempted connecting and records it, but rejects.

Here's the pg_hba.conf (Confirmed active -- changes do affect the service, but so far unable to connect over LAN

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust #Also tried md5 & peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust #Also tried md5 & peer
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust #Also tried md5 & peer
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust #Also tried md5 & peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust #Also tried md5 & peer
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust #Also tried md5 & peer
```

NOTE: All changes implemented are followed by `brew services restart postgresql@14`
And confirmed implemented by monitoring /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@14.log

in postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Server
MacOS Monterey 12.5
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.6 (Homebrew)

Client
MacOS Ventura 13.0.1

Comment: Your `pg_hba.conf` doesn't appear to allow any remote connections, so I'm not sure what else you expect.

Comment: Ok.  My (admittedly limited) understanding was the the lines showing "host" achieved that. What am I missing?

Comment: Your hba only allows "loopback" connections (that is, they might be TCP but are still within the same machine).

Comment: Documentation covers [this topic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) quite extensively; is there anything that remains unclear?

Comment: `host  all all ::1/128` only allows connections from the server where Postgres is running, not from any external IP

Comment: Got it working -- though not 100% clear on the meaning of the settings yet (still reading through) but basically changing the IPv4 host from 127.0.0.1/32 to 0.0.0.0/0 and IPv6 from ::1/128 to ::0/0 made the difference.  More to learn on all this, but at least it's sort of starting to make sense.  Thanks all.

Comment: Please post your comment to an answer then accept the answer after a few days. That way it will be easier for others to find your solution.

Comment: to resolved this issue try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76405239/pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-103-244-174-70-user-postgres-database-patientl/77236019)

Answer (score 1):

Solution here was to drill down on the Address column of pg_hba.conf and understand how the entries there allow/block traffic.

Thanks to [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) for helping clarify & [@mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) for the [postgres page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) on this.